# Sending data to web through command-line with javascript built-in

Tags: c#, java, javascript, c++

Webkit and Selenium use a browser interface to interact with javascript elements and send data. Is there a way where I can fill in a ajax form and send data straight from a command-line ? If not, why is it not possible ? If so, how ? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use my [terminal emulator jquery plugin](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/), but If you want to do AJAX when you don't have access to javascript source code you will need to create [Bookmarklet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bookmarklet)